# Can I restore restore content from old Worpress site to a new Worpress site from an archive

Tags: posts, pages, migration

I managed a now defunct Wordpress site (www.wp_old)several years ago that I still have complete archive of. It was created using Updraft Plus.

I recently configured a development server, and have started to build out a new Wordpress site (www.wp_new). I'd like to restore some of the content from www.wp_old to www.wp_new.

Is it possible to restore specific content from www.wp_old (e.g. mostly posts and pages, and associated media) to www.wp_new through an incremental restore of some sort? If not, would a workaround be to create a second development site with www.wp_old and the specific elements migrate from there?

Info if it helps:

- www.wp_new is running: WP 6.0.1, Selfhosted LAMP
- www.wp_old: offline for nearly three years, was commercially hosted

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a question for the Updraft Plus support channels - the solution will depend on the capabilities of that plugin and how the archive is formatted. And/or just install the Updraft Plus plugin on the new site and see what it offers

Comment: Figured if all else failed it would be the new site option. Thanks for the input.